# javascript returning a property and value pair of an object

Tags: javascript, object, closures

I am trying to have a new value pair added to my toaster object everytime I run the toast function, but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know why.
Here is the code:

```
var Toaster = function(){  
function cook(type,temp){ 
    var food = type;
    var amtCooked; 
    if(temp >7){
        amtCooked = "Well Done!"
    }
    else if(temp > 4){
        amtCooked = "Medium";
    }
    else{
        amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
    }
    this[food] = food + amtCooked;
}
return{
toast: function(typeOfBread,setting){
           cook(typeOfBread,setting)
       }
    };
}
```

I want to be able to invoke a function like

```
var v = Toaster();
v.toast("bread",4)
```

and the `v` should have `{bread:"medium"}`

But the `this[food]` part does not seem to be working.

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to be working"* How do you know? What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to mix the Factory and Constructor,
If you want to create a Toaster constructor, change to this:

```
var Toaster = function(){  
  function cook(type,temp){ 
    var food = type;
    var amtCooked; 
    if(temp >7){
    amtCooked = "Well Done!"
    }else if(temp > 4){
    amtCooked = "Medium";
    }else{
    amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
    }
    this[food] =food + amtCooked;
  }
  this.toast =function(typeOfBread,setting){
    cook.call(this, typeOfBread,setting);
  };
}

//Usage
var v = new Toaster();
v.toast("bread",4)
```

1. use new Toastser() will return a new object with the constructor function executed, and return itself, no need to return another object.
2. cook is a private function, and simply call `cook` makes the context ambiguous, use `cook.call(this)` to give it `context`, so `this[food]`'s this will be ref to the created toast object.

Or if you want a `ToasterFactory` then Code will like this:

```
var Toaster = function(){  
  function cook(type,temp){ 
      var food = type;
      var amtCooked; 
      if(temp >7){
          amtCooked = "Well Done!"
      }
      else if(temp > 4){
          amtCooked = "Medium";
      }
      else{
          amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
      }
      this[food] = food + amtCooked;
  }
  return {
    toast: function(typeOfBread,setting){
      cook.call(this, typeOfBread,setting);
    }
  };
}
//Usage
var v = Toaster();
v.toast("bread",4)
```

Created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v9a5hye/) for it. Based on the way you want to invoke Toaster, maybe `Factory` is what you want.

Comment: this is returning undefined

Comment: You have to use `var v = new Toaster();` to create an Toaster instance. What do you want?  A `Factory` that return a toaster upon call? or A `Constructor` that you create a instance of that.

Comment: Anyway, I've answer to both ways, choose one that you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var Toaster = function() {
    this.cooked = {};
}

Toaster.prototype.cook = function(type, temp) { 
    var food = type;
    var amtCooked; 
    if (temp > 7) {
        amtCooked = "Well Done!"
    } else if (temp > 4) {
        amtCooked = "Medium";
    } else {
        amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
    }
    this.cooked[food] = amtCooked;
}

Toaster.prototype.toast = function(typeOfBread, setting) {
    this.cook(typeOfBread, setting);
};

Toaster.prototype.history = function() {
    var record = '';
    Object.keys(this.cooked).forEach(function(typeOfBread) {
        record += typeOfBread + ': ' + this.cooked[typeOfBread] + '\n';
    }.bind(this));
    alert(record);
};

var t = new Toaster();

t.toast('Rye', 3);
t.toast('White', 3);
t.toast('Wheat', 10);

t.history();
```

Which then alerts:

```
Rye: Lightly done!
White: Lightly done!
Wheat: Well Done!
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypbybL9g/

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that you are looking for ?

```
var Toaster = function(){  
  function cook(type,temp){ 
      var food = type;
      var amtCooked; 
      if(temp >7){
        amtCooked = "Well Done!"
      }else if(temp > 4){
        amtCooked = "Medium";
      }else{
        amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
      }
      return {food : amtCooked};
  }
  return{
    toast: function(typeOfBread,setting){
      return cook(typeOfBread,setting)
    }
  };
}
var x = Toaster().toast("a", "b")
$(function(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
});
```

output generated = {"food":"Lightly done!"}

Comment: say var x = Toaster(), then x("bread",8); should return {"bread":"well done"}